# How to Duplicate Rocket Dock functionality

Tags: c#

I recently added [RocketDock](http://www.rocketdock.com) to my computer and love it.  It simulates the dock functionality from OS X.  I want to add this docking/hiding feature to one of my C# programs.

How do I program the ability to hide and show the dock when I roll over a certain space on my desk top?

I understand this may be pretty difficult so just a nudge in the right direction is all I'm really looking for.  Right now I have no idea what to even look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to take a look at [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/). In fact, CodePlex already has [an implementation](http://wpfdock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3210#93568) of what you want... not sure how good it is.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to look into the Win32 API for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I still have nightmares about that.